# O que é RootDSE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servidor, redes, ad

O gerente de minha empresa, me entregou um arquivo falando muito pouco sobre "rootDSE", e me disse que é uma forma de integrar o LDAP com as linguagens de programação.
Eu nunca ouvi falar desta forma, e não acho material necessário para entender se ele está certo.
A definição que me foi mais compreensível, foi esta:
"rootDSE é definida como a raiz da árvore de dados do diretório em um servidor de diretório. O rootDSE não faz parte de qualquer namespace. O objetivo do rootDSE é fornecer dados sobre o servidor de diretório. - Microsoft "

Porém, existe alguma forma de interação com o rootDSE e alguma linguagem de programação?
Ele é um arquivo, um comando, o que é exatamente?

Comment: veja se isso não te ajuda http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667301/How-to-query-Active-Directory-without-hard-coding

Comment: Ajudou sim, entendi e consegui recuperar os valores e entender como funciona.

Comment: Só não vi se tem a possibilidade de integração com as linguagens, ou se uso apenas para obter os valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Existe alguma forma de interação com o rootDSE e alguma linguagem de programação?

Existem várias. [Neste artigo colocado pelo @PabloVargas como comentário](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667301/How-to-query-Active-Directory-without-hard-coding), há exemplos em C#, VB.NET e IronPython.

## Ele é um arquivo, um comando, o que é exatamente?

Ele é uma estrutura de dados acessível através de uma classe chamada [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Essa estrutura de dados independe de linguagem, mas deve ser necessariamente uma linguagem que possa abordagem .NET, que é onde esta classe está implementada.

Tomando como exemplo para esta resposta o exemplo em C#:

```
        string defaultNamingContext;
        using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE"))
        {
            defaultNamingContext = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Accessing domain: {0}", defaultNamingContext);
```

Aqui ele está pedindo ao RootDSE a informação sobre o domínio onde a estrutura de dados está hospedada. [A lista completa de informações que pode ser requisitada está aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

## Só não vi se tem a possibilidade de integração com as linguagens, ou se uso apenas para obter os valores.

A integração deve ser escrita manualmente se assim desejar, caso o caminho seja mesmo o da leitura do RootDSE. Implementado mesmo é só o esquema de obtenção de valores.

[Ou então você pode ler este excelente artigo, que ensina várias formas de obter a informação que desejar no seu Active Directory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C).

Comment: Obrigado, essa explicação sanou minhas dúvidas.